# Specific dropdown menu for drupal

Tags: drupal

Noob needs help.
Can anybody advice a Drupal dropdown menu like this one? http://shopomio.ru/
The point is the full width of dropdown items list. Haven't found any menu modules like this one.
Or maybe anyone can tell how to get the menu items from drupal db. Seems rather strange to look through all this through drupal's taxonomy.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into this two popular drupal module for dropdown menu.This may help you.

[Responsive Dropdown Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_dropdown_menus)

[7 Mega Menu modules for Drupal](http://megadrupal.com/blog/7-mega-menu-modules-for-drupal)

Comment: Thank you) OM Maximenu from the second link is exactly this)